# How do I use Conky to monitor my mythtv backend?

Tags: conky, mythtv

I would like to use Conky to monitor a mythtv backend, how can I set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7057617) (Edited for content and grammar):

> I recently discovered this as I had a need for something else but I thought it might be nice to check the status of remote and local frontends.

- http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Telnet_socket

> I wrote a script that displays local and remote frontends status in conky and I would like to share it with you. I am just learning about scripting and this is my first attempt at variables i mostly just put stuff in that i could be typed type from shell with no variables or error correction so i learned a bit preparing this.
>
> The instructions on how to use are in the comments of the file and [this link](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Telnet_socket) should let you know about mythtv telnet and how to enable it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> The second screen shot shows how I use it combined with DemonBobs idea and conky mythtv recording status howto found here

```
#!/bin/bash
#Made By Kemble Wagner
#To use this Script you need to Enable Network Remote Control Interface on Mythfrontend
#Thanks to wagnerrp from mythtv-users on freenode for his contributions and tips
#the output files are meant to be used with conky
#e.g .conkyrc
#${color #8844ee}Local Frontend Status:
#${color #8844ee} ${execi 30 mythnc.sh > /dev/null && cat /var/tmp/local.myth}
#${color #8844ee}Remote Frontend Status:
#${color #8844ee} ${execi 30 mythnc.sh > /dev/null && cat /var/tmp/remote.myth}
#Version 0.2 14/04/09  
#Version 0.3 "       " fixed sed to make it parse long file names and unusual characters with spaces and no spaces when outputting Video Playback
#Version 0.4 "       " added more events to output in human friendly terms changes it so only one instance of nc is used to prevent hammering of ports
#Version 0.5 17/04/09 add some fixes to playback status and added a check status in the even the frontend not running but the host is up



#change the host names to suit add more if needed
LOCALHOST=box
#path to text file leave as default is ok 
OUTPUTFILE1=/var/tmp/local.myth
OUTPUTFILETMP1=/var/tmp/local.myth.tmp
FETEST1=/var/tmp/local.fetest
FILENAME1=`cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep 'Playback Video' |sed  -e 's/[[ \t]]*/_/g' | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' |  sed  's/  *//g' | sed -e 's/^.*\///;s/ .*$//'`
RECFILE1=`cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep 'Playback Recorded' |sed  -e 's/[[ \t]]*/_/g' | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' |  sed  's/  *//g' | sed -e 's/^.*\///;s/ .*$//'`
#remote host variables


#the stuff below is an attempt to convert telnet status info into human friendly readable info

#below are localhost checks

nc -c exit  $LOCALHOST 6546 && echo opened >  $FETEST1|| echo closed > $FETEST1


#Checking if MythFrontend is running 


if (cat $FETEST1 | grep closed ); then
  echo "$LOCALHOST is up but MythFrontend doesn't seem to be running" > $OUTPUTFILE1 

else
echo -e "query location\nexit" | nc $LOCALHOST 6546 > $OUTPUTFILETMP1
fi

#Checking for TV recording Menu
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep PlaybackBox ); then
  echo "$LOCALHOST is Idle in TV Recordings Menu" > $OUTPUTFILE1

else 

#Checking for Program Guide
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep GuideGrid ); then
  echo " $LOCALHOST is in TV Guide" > $OUTPUTFILE1
else 

#Checking for MythVideo Gallery
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep videogallery ); then
  echo "MythVideo Menu On $LOCALHOST is Idle" > $OUTPUTFILE1
else 

#Checking for MythVideo Listings
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep videolistings); then
  echo "MythVideo Menu On $LOCALHOST is Idle" > $OUTPUTFILE1
else 

#Checking for MythVideo Browser
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep videobrowser); then
  echo "MythVideo Menu On $LOCALHOST is Idle" > $OUTPUTFILE1
else 
#Checking for MythMusics
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep playmusic ); then
  echo "Playing Music Cant you Hear?" > $OUTPUTFILE1
else 

#Checking for MainMenu
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep MainMenu ); then
  echo "$LOCALHOST is in The Main Menu" > $OUTPUTFILE1

else 

#Checking for Live TV
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep "Playback LiveTV" ); then
  echo "$LOCALHOST is Watching Live TV" > $OUTPUTFILE1
else 

#Checking for MythVideo Playback
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep "Playback Video" ); then
  echo "MythVideo is playing $FILENAME1" > $OUTPUTFILE1
else 

if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep  "Playback Recorded" ); then
    echo "MythTV is playing recording $RECFILE1" > $OUTPUTFILE1
else





#if none of the above simply display then query status output
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep "#"); then 
cat   $OUTPUTFILETMP1 | grep "#" > $OUTPUTFILE1 


fi 
  fi 
     fi 
        fi   
           fi
              fi 
                fi
                  fi
                     fi
                        fi
                          fi




#setting remote host variables you can reproduce this for as many hosts as you want
REMOTE=frontend
OUTPUTFILE2=/var/tmp/remote.myth
OUTPUTFILETMP2=/var/tmp/remote.myth.tmp
# script gets slow if the host is not up when continueing to set remote host variables so check its up first
#checking remote frontend is up first
if ! `/bin/ping -W1 -c1 $REMOTE >/dev/null 2>&1` ; then
echo "$REMOTE Seems Offline" > $OUTPUTFILE2 && exit 0
else

#contine setting remote host variables 

FILENAME2=`cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep 'Playback Video' |sed  -e 's/[[ \t]]*/_/g' | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' |  sed  's/  *//g' | sed -e 's/^.*\///;s/ .*$//'`
RECFILE2=`cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep 'Playback Recorded' | sed -e 's/^.*\///;s/ .*$//' | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`
FETEST2=/var/tmp/remote.fetest


#below are remote host checks

nc -c exit $REMOTE 6546 && echo opened >  $FETEST2|| echo closed > $FETEST2

#Checking if MythFrontend is running 

if (cat $FETEST2 | grep closed ); then
  echo "$REMOTE is up but MythFrontend doesn't seem to be running" > $OUTPUTFILE2 

else

echo -e "query location\nexit" | nc $REMOTE 6546 > $OUTPUTFILETMP2
fi


#Checking for TV recording Menu
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep PlaybackBox ); then
  echo "$REMOTE is Idle in TV Recordings Menu" > $OUTPUTFILE2 
else 

#Checking for Program Guide
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep GuideGrid ); then
  echo "$REMOTE is in TV Guide" > $OUTPUTFILE2
else 

#Checking for MythVideo Gallery
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep videogallery ); then
  echo "MythVideo Menu On $REMOTE is Idle" > $OUTPUTFILE2
else 

#Checking for MythVideo Listings
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep videolistings); then
  echo "MythVideo Menu On $REMOTE is Idle" > $OUTPUTFILE2
else 

#Checking for MythVideo Browser
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep videobrowser); then
  echo "MythVideo Menu On $REMOTE is Idle" > $OUTPUTFILE2
else 

#Checking for MythMusics
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep playmusic ); then
  echo "Playing Music Cant you Hear?" > $OUTPUTFILE2
else 

#Checking for MainMenu
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep MainMenu ); then
  echo "$REMOTE is in The Main Menu" > $OUTPUTFILE2
else 

#Checking for Live TV
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep "Playback LiveTV" ); then
  echo "$REMOTE is Watching Live TV" > $OUTPUTFILE2
else 

#Checking for MythVideo Playback
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep "Playback Video" ); then
  echo "MythVideo On $REMOTE is playing $FILENAME2" > $OUTPUTFILE2
else 

if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep  "Playback Recorded" ); then
    echo "MythTV On $REMOTE is playing recording $RECFILE2" > $OUTPUTFILE2
else



#if none of the above simply display then query status output
if (cat $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep "#"); then 
cat   $OUTPUTFILETMP2 | grep "#" > $OUTPUTFILE2 



fi 
  fi 
     fi 
        fi   
           fi
              fi 
                fi 
                   fi
                      fi
                        fi
                          fi
                            fi 
                               fi
```

> I think it is pretty subtle considering how much I had to write in 
>   order to enable a few lines in conky. Anyway, this was fun for me i hope people try it and let me know how it goes post back if you need any help i would be glad to help if you have any problems setting it up.

#### References

- [Original Forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7057617) by oobe-feisty

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick comment on the mythtv-status option, you can set the host option in `/etc/default/mythtv-status` in which case it will be remembered if mythtv-status is upgraded or reinstalled.

You can also set other options like turn on colour output and add other information to the output.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a How-To on using conky on any ubuntu box to view recording info on your backend. This is accomplised by install mythtv-status on the ubuntu box that uses conky. I've modified mythtv-status a little bit.

1. Copy your `/home/username/.mythtv/config.xml` from your mythbuntu box to your local ubuntu desktop `/home/username/.mythtv/config.xml`
2. Edit the config.xml file to reflect the ip address of your backend

   ```
   gedit ~/.mythtv/config.xml
   ```

   Edit this line. Change localhost to the ip address of your backend. In my case

   ```
   <DBHostName>localhost</DBHostName>
   ```

   Changed to:

   ```
   <DBHostName>192.168.15.3</DBHostName>
   ```
3. Link config.xml to `/root/.mythtv/config.xml`

   ```
   sudo mkdir /root/.mythtv
   sudo ln -s ~/.mythtv/config.xml /root/.mythtv/config.xml
   ```

   This is to fix the perl api warning in mythtv status.
4. Install mythtv-status

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install mythtv-status
5. Edit mythtv-status to reflect my changes.

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/bin/mythtv-status
   ```

   Around line 21. Change localhost to ip address of backend

   ```
   my $host = "localhost";
   ```

   In my instance it changes to.

   ```
   my $host = "192.168.15.3";
   ```
6. Edit .conkyrc file to add output.

   ```
   gedit ~.conkyrc
   ```

   Near the top add:

   ```
   text_buffer_size 1024
   ```

   At the bottom add

   ```
   ${color #0077ff} ${execi 300 perl /usr/bin/mythtv-status KISP}
   ```

Change the colors to correspond to your current .conkyrc config.

Run conky to test.

#### References

- [Original Forum Post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=934264) by DemonBob